# retrieve cross sell product in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce

I have been here for the last 5 hours trying to figure out something. I need to be able to fetch the cross sell id of a product in the woo commerce in the order confirmation email. Up to now I have

```
         $items = $order->get_items(); 
        foreach ( $items as $item ) {
            $product_id = $item['product_id'];
            }
```

And this retrive the id of the product. As there is always just going to be one cross sell product how can I get the id of that product in a variable?

This will be the last part of an affiliated program I am building for a guy but I now if fetches the purchased product id and I need the cross-sell one.

Comment: cross sell?  you want to show product sell?

Comment: Woocommerce allows you to add up sell products and up sells. I would need to know how to fetch the cross sell one's is in the order email

Answer (score 18):

```
<?php global $product;
$cross_sell_ids = $product->get_cross_sell_ids(); ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

First you need cross sell product id for that product 
so it can be like:

```
$crosssellProductIds   =   get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_crosssell_ids' );
$crosssellProductIds    =   $crosssellProductIds[0];
```

Now as we have all related cross cell product's id,  let's get there information

```
foreach($crosssellProductIds as $id):
    $crosssellProduct = wc_get_product( $id );
    print_r($crosssellProduct);
endforeach;
```

Comment: I have tried this code but seem it's not working. are you sure it work ?